# Mimic Vat and Exiling

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I used [Mimic Vat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mimic%20Vat) on a [Licid](http://magiccards.info/query?q=t%3Alicid&v=card&s=cname), created a copy of that Licid, and attached it to a creature, would I still have to exile it during my end step even though it's now an enchantment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The relevant part of Mimic Vat's text reads:

> Put a token onto the battlefield that's a copy of the exiled card. It gains haste. Exile it at the beginning of the next end step.

The text clearly tells you to exile the token that the Vat created regardless of whether it's a creature or not.  If a Licid token becomes an enchantment, it is still the same object and thus still the same token, and so the Vat's delayed triggered ability will still find it and exile it at the next end step.

Comment: It may be worth emphasizing that the reason this is clear (i.e. the reason it's clear you exile the token whether it's a creature or not) is simply that the text does not say anything about it being or not being a creature. It's an often-quoted rule of thumb that Magic cards should be taken literally except when the rules specify otherwise; this is a prime example.

Comment: @DavidZ, That's not really true. Take for example "Create an enchantment token (with some characteristics) and a creature token (with some characteristics). Exile the creature token at the beginning of the next end step." From what you say, it sounds like it will only exile a creature token, except it will still exile it even if it's no longer a creature.

Comment: @ikegami As I said, it's a rule of thumb; there are rare exceptions, such as the one you brought up. That being said, are you sure it would actually be templated that way?

Comment: @DavidZ, You actually said it was a prime example, but I showed otherwise. Yes, there are things templated that way. e.g. [Diabolic Servitude](http://magiccards.info/pd3/en/22.html).

Comment: @ikegami (1) no, you didn't. jwodder's answer _is_ a prime example of the literal interpretation being the correct one, and nothing you said refutes that. If you'd like to discuss this further it's probably time to move it to chat. (2) Thanks; I couldn't think of an example offhand so I wasn't sure.

Comment: I've proven it's wrong to interpret it literally, so it can't possibly be a prime example of the literal interpretation being the correct one